# Duplicating values in a data frame conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that in an entirely simplistic representation looks like this:

```
structure(list(Plant = c("rose", "rose", "rose", "rose", "rose", 
"rose", "rose", "rose", "cactus", "cactus", "cactus", "cactus"
), Area = c("North", "North", "North", "North", "South", "South", 
"South", "South", "South", "South", "South", "South"), dups = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

For any row of plant, I want to replace it with specific possible combinations of plant and area that are within another data frame. They are not ALL possible combinations, but just the ones that truly exist.

The possible combinations of the variables look like this:

```
structure(list(nam = c("rose", "rose", "rose", "rose", "cactus", 
"cactus"), area = c("North", "South", "East", "West", "South", 
"Northwest")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The final dataset should look like:

```
   structure(list(Plant2 = c("rose", "rose", "rose", "rose", "rose", 
 "rose", "rose", "rose", "cactus", "cactus", "cactus", "cactus"
 ), Area2 = c("North", "South", "East", "West", "North", "South", 
 "East", "West", "South", "Northwest", "South", "Northwest")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -12L))
```

This is how I started. I created a variable for how many combinations were potentially possible and added them to the datframe with a join. And then I got super stuck because try as I might, I can't change the Area variables properly. I thought I could basically paste all the combinations of the variables with the same dups value, but I can't call to the other dataframe from dplyr. This is a very simplistic version of the data, there are many other combinations and so it's not really want to do by subsetting the data, etc...

```
dups<-combos %>% group_by(nam) %>% mutate(dups=n())
colnames(dups)<-c("Plant","Area","dups")
df<-left_join(df,dups)
df<-df %>% uncount(dups, .remove=FALSE)
```

Comment: Are we to ignore `Area` in the first data frame altogether, then? It seems like you just want to write over it with the plant-specific areas.

Comment: Yes. That's what I concluded might be the simplest way to get to the df2. It's hard to explain simplistically. Basically I'm trying to replicate to show gaps in a time series that will then be plotted longitudinally on different plots according to "Area". If I don't have an area for every plant, then I miss the plant when subsetting according to area.

Comment: Assuming you have data frames named `df1` and `df2`, you can try something like `df1 %>% filter(row_number() %% dups == 0) %>% left_join(df2, by = c("Plant" = "nam"))`. Might need to group prior to filtering if your data isn't appropriately sorted.

Comment: Hi Richie, Thank you for your comment, but it's throwing me an error about non-numeric argument to binary operator.  I'm not sure I understand what the code is doing........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you have provided is not enough to produce a final dataframe like that since each combination of `Plant` and `dups` in `df` can be mapped to multiple values in `combos`. For instance, each `"rose"` and `"4"` could be matched against the first four rows in `combos`. However, it seems that you simply want `Area2` to repeat itself until the values fill up all possible entries for each group of `Plant` and `dups`. If so, you can try

```
library(dplyr)

combos <- combos %>% group_by(nam) %>% mutate(dups = n())
df %>% 
  group_by(Plant, dups) %>% 
  mutate(Area2 = rep(
    combos$area[combos$nam == Plant[[1L]] & combos$dups == dups[[1L]]], 
    length.out = n()
  ))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Plant, dups [2]
   Plant  Area   dups Area2    
   <chr>  <chr> <int> <chr>    
 1 rose   North     4 North    
 2 rose   North     4 South    
 3 rose   North     4 East     
 4 rose   North     4 West     
 5 rose   South     4 North    
 6 rose   South     4 South    
 7 rose   South     4 East     
 8 rose   South     4 West     
 9 cactus South     2 South    
10 cactus South     2 Northwest
11 cactus South     2 South    
12 cactus South     2 Northwest
```

Comment: You're right, actually I made a mistake in my example of the final frame. It should be four rows for every Rose and two for every cactus, and I started out with four roses, so should have been total of 24 rows. Oops! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand.grid` to create a dataframe with all possible conditions

```
expand.grid(name = unique(df$name), area = unique(df$area))

    Plant      Area
1    rose     North
2  cactus     North
3    rose     South
4  cactus     South
5    rose      East
6  cactus      East
7    rose      West
8  cactus      West
9    rose Northwest
10 cactus Northwest
```

Comment: Hi Macgregor, thank you for your comment, but I don't want all possible combinations, just the combinations noted in the combos data frame. I revised my request to be more clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do what you want, if I've understood correctly. Here, `d1` and `d2` are your first and second data frames. I don't think that computing `dups` as you have is necessary for this task, but maybe I've misunderstood your intention.

```r
library("dplyr")

l <- split(d2$area, d2$nam)
d1 %>% 
  group_by(Plant) %>% 
  mutate(Area = rep_len(l[[Plant[1L]]], n())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-dups)
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   Plant  Area     
   <chr>  <chr>    
 1 rose   North    
 2 rose   South    
 3 rose   East     
 4 rose   West     
 5 rose   North    
 6 rose   South    
 7 rose   East     
 8 rose   West     
 9 cactus South    
10 cactus Northwest
11 cactus South    
12 cactus Northwest
```